# Get the value of <option> from views to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Since 'HTML' do not have the attribute 'name',I am looking for a way to accept the value, which I populated in views, in the controller and assign it a variable name for another use.
This is sample of my code:`

```
enter code here<form action="<%=url_for(:action =>:make_comment) %>">

<fieldset>
<select>
<%@category.each {|x|%>
<option id="label"> <%=x%></option>
 <%}%>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>`
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Could you supply an example to help illustrate?

Comment: perhaps you should try a Ruby on Rails tutorial to learn the basics of Rails. A good starting point: http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts

Comment: It's more basic than that. We're not even really talking about rails, just forms. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that your html doesn't have a `name` attribute? If so, why?

The name attribute is what the server will interpret as the "key" for the value that you are sending. I don't know what other way you could try to go about doing this.

Maybe if you paste some code from your controller and your view, I could give a better answer.

Edit: After seeing your edited question, what you want to do is have your `select` tag with the `name` attribute, and your `option` tags have a `value` attribute with the value you want to send.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I am saying that the OPTION tag in HTML do not accept a name attribute, I just edited the question now with the code I am using.

Comment: If it solved your problem, than you should reward theIV for his work, because that is how SO works. Please accept and if you want vote up his answer

Answer (score 2):

This example show how you create a select tag:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {})
```

In this case, you would be able to get (in your controller) the value of the selected option through

```
params[:post][:person_id]
```

Is this what you want? Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have it now.